# Can't wrap my head around capturing form data (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, forms, authentication

I am simply trying to create a mockup of a login page, and need to get the `username` and `password` values entered into the form, and use those values to validate whether the user should be authenticated. I've looked at a dozen tutorials and can't seem to understand it fully. Here is what I have:

login.component.html

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="loginUser()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" 
        [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel"
        class="form-control" required>

      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" 
      [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel"
      class="form-control" required>
    <div style="padding-top:20px">
      <button type=submit class="button">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

login.component.ts (I'm going wrong here somewhere, but I tried. The "if" statement is definitely wrong)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm, FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  myForm: FormGroup

  constructor(private router: Router) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loginUser(f: NgForm) {
    if (f.value == "admin" && f.value == "admin"){
      this.router.navigate(['mockup']);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1- Model is not defined anywhere. Therefore, model.username is not valid. Just make it username or define model somewhere in your calss.

2-You don't need the variables (#username="ngModel") if you are not going to use them in the template. For example, you could do:

```
<input #myUsernameInput="ngModel">

{{ myUsernameInput.valid }} // true/false
{{ myUsernameInput.value }} the value
```

and various other checks. But you aren't performing these checks anywhere, so there's no need to have the variables defined.

3- myForm should not be defined in your class, as formGroups are used for reactive forms, not template driven forms. If you want to pass the values to the method, an easy way is like this:

```
<form (submit)="loginUser(username, password)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" 
        [(ngModel)]="username" class="form-control" required>

      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" 
      [(ngModel)]="password" class="form-control" required>
    <div style="padding-top:20px">
      <button type=submit class="button">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>



import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm, FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loginUser(username: string, password: string) {
    if (username === "admin" && password === "admin"){
      this.router.navigate(['mockup']);
    }
  }
}
```

The easiest way to to explain template driven forms means that all the work (meaning the building of the form, the validation, etc.) takes place in the template (the html). This is limited because you can't do everything that you could with reactive driven forms. However, reactive driven forms are a bit more complex. Which to choose depends on the situation and the preference, but in this scenario, template driven forms are perfectly valid to use. I'd recommend reading this guide, it's super helpful. https://angular.io/guide/forms